# Unable to switch subscription plan in Woocommerce with AJAX Add to cart option enabled

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

So I am using [Woocommerce subscriptions plugin](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/) along with an [AJAX side cart plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/side-cart-woocommerce/). I don't face any issue when adding subscription product to cart for the first purchase. It's only when the customer decides to switch their subscription plan that all the discrepancies occur. The product is not being added to cart. It doesn't matter whether the AJAX call is made by the plugin or by woocommerce, the product is not getting added to cart.

I might have found the cause for it in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68830408/add-woocommerce-subscription-switch-to-cart-programmatically#:%7E:text=The%20main%20issue%20is%20that%20Woocommerce%20thinks%20that%20a%20subscription%20product%20is%20unpurchaseable%20when%20it%20is%20added%20to%20the%20cart%20any%20other%20way%20than) but I'm not 100% sure if the solution would actually work, so if anyone can guide a little noob out here, it would be of great help.

On a side note, I have posted another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72912467/disable-ajax-add-to-cart-button-for-specific-product) on this site, asking for a more specific solution to this exact same problem. If someone would answer that question rather than this one, they're more than welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Log what is happening when you add,remove,update cart. Most of the time the product is added and removed in same time. But that is more to plugin/theme related problem. So contact plugin devs and see what they think about that.

Comment: I may have forgotten to mention a small detail. Everything works perfectly fine when AJAX is disabled for the add to cart buttons. It's only when using the AJAX function when things go south.